# Decimal.Parse doesn't remove trailing zeros

Tags: c#, vb.net

*Please read the question before flagging as duplicate.*

I found many questions on SO complaining that `Decimal.Parse` **doesn't keep** trailing zeros. But for my case `Decimal.Parse(String)` **doesn't remove** trailing zeros at all.

```
Decimal.Parse("3.000").ToString() ' ==> "3.000"
Double.Parse("3.000").ToString() ' ==> "3"
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Decimal remembers the number of significant digits in the fraction.  Feature, not a bug.  Format the value the way you want it, like ToString("N2") to get 2 digits in the fraction.

Comment: @HansPassant Right, or -for my case- `ToString("G29")`. Thanks!

Comment: ToString("G");  try this

Comment: What is the desired result for `3.100`?

Comment: Why the down voting tho?! @MartinSmith, for my case, the desired result would be `3.1`.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, apparently you're correct. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [number formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Decimal.Parse("3.100").ToString("G")
```

Or with some workaround like the following:

```
StrDec = Decimal.Parse("3.100").ToString

If strDec.Contains(".") Then strdec = strdec.TrimEnd("0")
```