# Format decimal number with digit grouping and limit the number of digits

Tags: c#, vb.net, string-formatting

Basically I'm trying to perform number formatting in the exact same way as the Windows calculator does. Hence, my requirements are:

- Limit the number of displayed digits to a maximum (e.g. 16). I was able to accomplish that using `number.ToString("G16")`.
- Add digit grouping to the number. I was able to accomplish that using: `number.ToString(String.Format("#,0.{0};-#,0.{0}", New String("#"c, 15)))`

Any ideas on how to combine these together to get the same behavior as Windows calculator?

---

**Some examples with the desired output:**

[image: Examples]

---

I added an answer below which I would be using if the desired output can't be achieved using one string formatting. Feel free to suggest any optimizations/changes to that answer if you believe no direct way to achieve this (which is my original requirement)

Sorry if I caused some kind of confusion to anyone. I just thought that there might be a simple one string formatting to achieve this and I was -and still am- curious to find out if that's true.

Comment: You should probably give examples. For example, can you give a number for which your approach in the second bullet does not output the desired string? What is the actual string, and what did you want?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, updated the question.

Comment: [I already told you how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40953111/17034).   Use Math.Log10(Math.Abs(value)) to know when you need to switch to the "E" format.

Comment: @HansPassant, I know about your comment there and I used something similar (my second bullet point) that doesn't produce extra zeros. Is there an advantage of using `ToString("N")`? Second, I'm not sure I understand how `Math.Log10` would help. Also "*I'm seeking a way to achieve the desired output using ONLY string formatting (or similar straight-forward method)*" if there's one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of search on this issue. You cannot perform this with a single format because you are asking about an `IF .. ELSE` LOGIC not for a one-way formatting (*performing two formatting on a number*)

```
IF d.ToString("G16") contains scientific notation

    ... do something

ELSE

    ... group digits
```

So you have to use an `IF` to achieve this

```
Str = If( num.ToString("G15").Contains("e"), num.ToString("G15"), num.ToString(String.Format("#,0.{0};-#,0.{0}", New String("#"c, 15))))
```

**Update1**

Based on your update use the following

```vb
Public Function FormatDouble(ByVal dbl As Double, ByVal len As Integer) As String

    Return Double.Parse(dbl.ToString("G" & len)).ToString("#,#.#".PadRight(len, "#"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

End Function
```

- `dbl.ToString("G" &len)` is formatting `dbl` to a fixed length = `len`
- `Double.parse` is converting the result again to double with the new length. *Note: if th result contains `e` it will be removed after parse*
- `ToString("#,#.#".PadRight(len, "#"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` is adding Group digits to the resulted double

**Note**

When providing length `("G15")` it will round the number to it. It may reduce length from decimal part but it doesn't from the integers it will round the number to the specified length. I.e. `1734.Tostring("G1")`  will returns `2000` but not `2` / `1734.Tostring("G2")`  will returns `1700` but not `17`

If you want to reduce numbers you have to use *String Functions* like `Substring` And `Left` after the `Tostring("G1")`

Hope it helps

Comment: That won't even combine the advantages of both methods. You'll always end up using only one of them while I need both together (limit number of digits + group digits). Also, the `e` isn't the only issue that the condition should be based on. Thanks for your effort though :)

Comment: Your example does not show what you are saying. I dont see any combination ??!! When scientific notation is found no grouping is allowed

Comment: "*Any ideas on how to combine these together to get the same behavior as Windows calculator*". The question isn't about combining scientific notation and digit grouping. It's about combining *digit grouping* and *limiting the number of digits* (`G16` does that as long as the scientific notation if needed).

Comment: I updated the question trying to clear up any misunderstanding. BTW, of course I know that *when scientific notation is found no grouping is allowed*. That's why I wasn't asking to combine these two together in the first place. I never mentioned scientific notation in my question. The example only displayed it because `G16` **which rounds/limits the number of digits** also **does scientific notation**. I hope it's clear now :)

Comment: If the output of `ToString("G")` contains an `e`, the second `ToString` will throw a `FormatException`. Try `FormatDouble(100, 2)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130213/discussion-between-ahmed-abdelhameed-and-hadi).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know an easy way to do that in the way you are looking for.

But being a curious sort of fellow I did wonder how it could be achieved using only string methods.

To be clear, I'm not advocating this approach as a good solution - it's rather hard to understand in one line, but hey, an interesting exercise for me.

If you felt like doing it in one horrendous line (c#):

```
var num1 = 123123123.456456456;  // result: 123,123,123.4564565
//var num1 = 123123123456456456.78;  // result: 1.231231234564565E+17
//var num1 = 123123123456; // result: 1,231,231,234,564,564
//var num1 = 1231231; // result: 1,231,231

Console.WriteLine(long.Parse((num1.ToString("G16") + ".").Substring(0, (num1.ToString("G16") + ".").IndexOf('.'))).ToString("N0") + (num1.ToString("G16") + ".").Substring((num1.ToString("G16") + ".").IndexOf('.'), (num1.ToString("G16") + ".").LastIndexOf('.')- (num1.ToString("G16") + ".").IndexOf('.')));
```

Otherwise broken up a little; it's a little clearer what approach I'm taking:

```
var num1 = 123123123.456456456;
var num1a = num1.ToString("G16") + "."; 

Console.WriteLine(long.Parse(num1a.Substring(0, num1a.IndexOf('.'))).ToString("N0") + num1a.Substring(num1a.IndexOf('.'), num1a.LastIndexOf('.')- num1a.IndexOf('.')));
```

I'm adding a decimal point to the end of the string so that there is at least one decimal point in the number (string). Then grab the text to the left of the first decimal point and concatenate it with any text from the first and to the left of the last decimal point.

If there was no decimal point in the original string then these two points are the same - the substring 0 characters long - removing the added decimal point.

Comment: Maybe not just string methods... I snuck a `long.Parse()` in there

Comment: +1 Good answer too. However, I could've written my answer into a one line of code as well, but that's not the point. I just thought there might be a one string formatting to achieve this (something like `num.ToString("SOME_SORT_OF_FORMATTING")`. But looks like that's not possible. That's why I accepted Hadi's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**This is an answer I would be using if this can't be done using one string formatting:**

```vb
Private Function RoundAndGroup(num As Decimal) As String
    ' This will round the input to limit the number of digit to 16.
    Dim rounded As String = num.ToString("G16")
    ' Take only the whole part of the number to group and then combine with the rounded part.
    Dim whole As String = rounded.Split(".")(0)
    ' Group the whole part (if any) and combine with the rounded part (also if any).
    Dim grouped As String = Long.Parse(whole).ToString("N0") & ' Thanks to KScandrett's comment
                            rounded.Substring(whole.Length)
    Return grouped
End Function
```

This will -AFAICT- produce my desired output (the same output of Windows calculator).

I just thought that there might be a simple one string formatting to achieve this and I was -and still am- curious to find out if that's true.

Comment: You could use `Integer.Parse(whole).ToString(String.Format("N0")) & ...` in `grouped`

Comment: @KScandrett, +1 Good point. Yes, since I'm applying this formatting to the whole part only, there will be no trailing zeros. Also I should be using `Long` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx) to apply multiple formats. Read about [Composite Formatting here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
String.Format("{0:N0}", Clng(number.ToString("G16")))
```

[Tested in vb.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2tBCAb)

You can drop the zeros or use your formatting, but the original question was about applying multiple formats.

You <s>might</s> **need** to convert the number to long while formatting, test it out at your end.

For part 2, you can just use `N0` to add the commas for thousands places - [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This cannot work. You cannot format twice. After the first formatting, in your case the `.ToString("G16")`, what you have is a string. That string will not care about the `N0` thing. A string is not formattable (and `string` does not implement `IFormattable`).

Comment: Did you read my comment? `You might need to convert the number to long while formatting, test it out at your end.` Obviously i didnt test it and have mentioned about it. But anyway, since you did test it, I'll add it

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, exactly. TheUknown, thank you for the suggestion but it doesn't work.

Comment: So you say I apply the `G16` first, to get something like `"3.14"`, say, how can I go through `long` from there to apply `N0` afterwards?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I'm not good with c# i used converter but here's an [example in vb.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2tBCAb)

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Check out the updated answer with fiddle, its a vb.net example

Comment: But it does not give the desired output, for the asker wants `"1.11111111111111e18"` in that case. And it cannot work for numbers that are not whole, such as `2.5`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Alright got it now, you are correct. `it cannot work for numbers that are not whole`. Question to OP : why dont you just apply group format and then strip the string to 16 characters?

Comment: You probably meant `CDec` or `CDbl`. But anyway that won't give the desired output (limiting number of digits).

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN Cant you use `Substring` method to get only first 16 characters? or if you have the user entering a number somewhere then restrict input ot max 14 characters?

Comment: @TheUknown, well it won't be just that, I'll have to first check the number of digits before the decimal point, compare that to the maximum, and then decide whether to group digits or use eX. But yes it can be done manually like that. I'm just wondering if there's a direct way to perform this (e.g using string formatting).

Answer (score 0):

```
static formatDecimal(decimal decimalVar, int size)
{
    return decimalVar.ToString("#.##").PadLeft(size, '0'); 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer is appreciated, it would be even better if you [edited your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63488306/edit) to add an explanation for your code. That would make your answer more useful, and more likely to be upvoted :)